# how to plot all the columns of a data frame in R and keep the column names

Tags: r

I am trying to make graphs from my data, with one graph per column in my dataframe. I can get it to run, but can't keep the column names. 
I have tried this:

```
for (c in x.sub)(
  print(qplot(c, T8641, data=x.sub, geom = c("point", "smooth"),
              ylab="Cumulative number of Patients infected after 7 Days",
              xlab = x.sub[c])))
```

I've tried to look at other examples on stack overflow, but don't understand them. Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: that adds all the values in the column to the axis, rather than the name of the column

Comment: names(x.sub)[c], possibly with paste() around it

Comment: You need to `for(c in names(x.sub)) qplot(x.sub[[c]]... + xlab=c`